# Using eventlet to process large number of https requests with large data returns

Tags: json, xml, eventlet

I am trying to use eventlets to process a large number of data requests, approx. 100,000 requests at a time to a remote server, each of which should generate a 10k-15k byte JSON response. I have to decode the JSON, then perform some data transformations (some field name changes, some simple transforms like English->metric, but a few require minor parsing), and send all 100,000 requests out the back end as XML in a couple of formats expected by a legacy system. I'm using the code from the eventlet example which uses imap() "for body in pool.imap(fetch, urls):...."; lightly modified. eventlet is working well so far on a small sample (5K urls), to fetch the JSON data. My question is whether I should add the non-I/O processing (JSON decode, field transform, XML encode) to the "fetch()" function so that all that transform processing happens in the greenthread, or should I do the bare minimum in the greenthread, return the raw response body, and do the main processing in the "for body in pool.imap():" loop? I'm concerned that if I do the latter, the amount of data from completed threads will start building up, and will bloat memory, where doing the former would essentially throttle the process to where the XML output would keep up. Suggestions as to preferred method to implement this welcome. Oh, and this will eventually run off of cron hourly, so it really has a time window it has to fit into. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you put each data processing operation into separate green thread. Then, *only when required*, combine several operations into batch or use a pool to throttle concurrency.

When you do non-IO-bound processing in one loop, essentially you throttle concurrency to 1 simultaneous task. But you can run those in parallel using (OS) thread pool in `eventlet.tpool` module.

Throttle concurrency only when you have too many parallel CPU-bound code running.